# android execution in emulator or device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, device

Is there any way to know if my application is running on the emulator or on the device ?

Answer (score 4):

I am using this code snippet which works on both Intel and ARM emulators:

```
if (Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk") ||
    Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator") ||
    Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK")) {
  RunsInEmulator = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

(where `Secure` is `android.provider.Settings.Secure`)

That value will be `null` on the emulator, non-null on devices.

Comment: It doesn't work with emulator running in 2.2. It returns an ID.

Comment: @Arutha: Yes, that is new behavior for Android 2.2