# Is it reliable to check if Build.SERIAL is "unknown" to recognise emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion, bluestacks

I want to know if my app is running not on real device (on any emulator) and if so - change app's behaviour. There was a topic 4 years ago [How to find out from code if my Android app runs on emulator or real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864251/how-to-find-out-from-code-if-my-android-app-runs-on-emulator-or-real-device) but all these methods are not valid. 
I found that emulators return "unknown" for Build.SERIAL. But in official documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html it is said: public static final String SERIAL - A hardware serial number, if available. Alphanumeric only, case-insensitive.
So the question is - can there by unknown serial on real device?